# Pass parameter to Angular ng-include

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-include, angularjs-ng-init

I am trying to display a binary tree of elements, which I go through recursively with ng-include.

What is the difference between `ng-init="item = item.left"` and `ng-repeat="item in item.left"` ?
In this example it behaves exactly the same, but I use similiar code in a project and there it behaves differently. I suppose it's because of Angular scopes.
Maybe I shouldn't use ng-if, please explain me how to do it better.

The pane.html is:

```
<div ng-if="!isArray(item.left)">
    <div ng-repeat="item in [item.left]" ng-include="'Views/pane.html'">
    </div>
</div>
<div ng-if="isArray(item.left)">
    {{item.left[0]}}
</div>
<div ng-if="!isArray(item.right)">
    <div ng-repeat="item in [item.right]" ng-include="'Views/pane.html'">
    </div>
</div>
<div ng-if="isArray(item.right)">
    {{item.right[0]}}
</div>

<div ng-if="!isArray(item.left)">
    <div ng-init = "item = item.left" ng-include="'Views/pane.html'">
    </div>
</div>
<div ng-if="isArray(item.left)">
    {{item.left[0]}}
</div>
<div ng-if="!isArray(item.right)">
    <div ng-init="item = item.right" ng-include="'Views/pane.html'">
    </div>
</div>
<div ng-if="isArray(item.right)">
    {{item.right[0]}}
</div>
```

The controller is:

```
var app = angular.module('mycontrollers', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {

    $scope.tree = {
        left: {
            left: ["leftleft"],
            right: {
                left: ["leftrightleft"],
                right: ["leftrightright"]
            }
        },
        right: {
            left: ["rightleft"],
            right: ["rightright"]
        }
    };

    $scope.isArray = function (item) {
        return Array.isArray(item);
    }
});
```

EDIT:
First I run into the problem that the directive ng-repeat has a greater priority than ng-if. I tried to combine them, which failed. IMO it's strange that ng-repeat dominates ng-if.

Comment: A solution is create a new directive, as i said in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36916276/2516399

Answer (score 52, accepted):

> Pass parameter to Angular ng-include

You don't need that. all `ng-include`'s sources have the same controller. So each view sees the same data.

> What is the difference between ng-init="item = item.left" and ng-repeat="item in item.left"

*[[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19691917/how-do-display-a-collapsible-tree-in-angularjs-bootstrap/19692791#19692791)]*

`ng-init="item = item.left"` means - creating new instance named item that equals to `item.left`.  In other words you achieve the same by writing in controller:

```
$scope.item = $scope.item.left
```

---

*[2]*

`ng-repeat="item in item.left"` means create list of scopes based on `item.left` array. You should know that each item in `ng-repeat` has its private scope

---

> I am trying to display a binary tree of elements, which I go through recursively with ng-include.

I posted in the past answer how to display tree by using `ng-include`.

It might helpful:  <kbd>[how-do-display-a-collapsible-tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19691917/how-do-display-a-collapsible-tree-in-angularjs-bootstrap/19692791#19692791)</kbd>

The main part here that you create *Node* with `id` wrapped by `<scipt>` tag and use `ng-repeat`:

```
  <script type="text/ng-template"  id="tree_item_renderer">
        <ul class="some" ng-show="data.show"> 
          <li ng-repeat="data in data.nodes" class="parent_li"  ng-include="'tree_item_renderer'" tree-node></li>
        </ul>
  </script>


<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="data in displayTree"  ng-include="'tree_item_renderer'"></li>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It was really helpful. I'll try to write a directive, similiar to your diretives `'node'` and `'nodeTree'`

Answer (score 52):

It's a little hacky, but I am passing variables to an ng-include with an ng-repeat of an array containing a JSON object :

```
<div ng-repeat="pass in [{'text':'hello'}]" ng-include="'includepage.html'"></div>
```

In your include page you can access your variable like this:

```
<p>{{pass.text}}</p>
```

Comment: Definitely hacky, but I'm totally using it!

Comment: #MEGA. Not perfect for long term, but as I'm going through a huge refactor this is coming in handy

Comment: What dark magic is this?! 
It's so simple that I cant believe I haven't thought of this before.
I need to display multiple contacts off of a single object, and the contact view has been extracted to template html, but passing in each contact without hard coding it was eluding me. Thanks for this!

Comment: @Jamadan, what options are better for a long term from you pov? :)

Comment: @hellouworld - lol, I don't even remember what project I was working on here. Haven't written Angular since this I think! I have a vague memory of updating some of the data structures coming back from my API so that I didn't need to do this. Sorry can't be of more help.

Answer (score 5):

Making a generic directive instead of ng-include is a cleaner solution:
[Angular passing scope to ng-include](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25678560/angular-passing-scope-to-ng-include)

Answer (score 3):

I am using ng-include with ng-repeat of an array containing string. If you want to send multple data so please see [Junus Ergin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25565475/pass-parameter-to-angular-ng-include#answer-34019586) answer.

See my code Snippet:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="">
<div ng-repeat="name in ['Sanjib Pradhan']" ng-include="'your_template.html'"></div>
<div ng-repeat="name in ['Chinmay Sahu']" ng-include="'your_template.html'"></div>


    <script type="text/ng-template" id="your_template.html">
          {{name}}
    </script>
  </div>
```