# How to send parameter to angular template?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I'm using Angular with ASP.NET MVC. In one of my razor views I include an angular template, like:

```
@model myViewModel;
...
<div ng-include src="'/App/myTemplate.html'"></div>
...
```

This works just fine, and the template shows as expected. But I would like to send a parameter from my MVC view model to the template, similar to:

```
<div ng-include src="'/App/myTemplate.html'" param="@myViewModel.subTitle"></div>
```

Is there some way this can be done?

---

UPDATE:

I got it to work with the onload parameter, like this:

```
@model myViewModel;
...
<div ng-include src="'/App/myTemplate.html'" onload="tell='@myViewModel.subTitle'"></div>
...
```

In myTemplate.html I have:

```
Here is the parameter from master view {{tell}}
```

I got the inspiration from over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25678560/angular-passing-scope-to-ng-include).

Comment: why not rather use a directive? You can then pass in the parameters as you need.

Comment: It's a rather big template, so a directive would maybe not fit that purpose.

Comment: are you going to re-use the template?

Comment: No I don't plan to use it anywhere else.

Comment: Can you not use `ng-init` for this?

Something like: 

`<div ng-include src="'/App/myTemplate.html'" ng-init="init(@JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model))"></div>`

Comment: @Namrehs: I cannot get that to work.