# Pass variable value to ng-include-variables in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have the following in my tmpl file:

```
<div ng-include="include.tmpl" 
     ng-include-variables="{ text: {{ "global.login.text" | translate }} }"></div>
```

I get errors doing this. There must be a way I can pass the value of:

```
{{ "global.login.text" | translate }}
```

as "text" to my include.tmpl.

Does anyone know?

Comment: I believe you can wrap `{{ "global.login.text" | translate }}` in single quotes. My suspicion is the nested {{}} are evaluated as interpolation by angular.

Comment: You can pass them as text and translate them inside `include.html`

Comment: @Gregg The single quote doesn't work

Comment: `ng-include-variables` isn't a thing AFAIK.  (Some answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25678560/angular-passing-scope-to-ng-include) use it as an attribute name for a custom directive, is that where you got it?)  That question appears to contain the answer to this one, in any case