# Bootstrap-UI - How to use TemplateUrl for a tab view without manipulating the URL?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angularjs-ng-include

I'm working on some [Bootstrap-UI tabs](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/tabs), but I can't find an instance online that uses `templateURL` without manipulating the URL of the page. Here's what I'd like to do:

HTML

```
<uib-tabset active="active">
    <uib-tab ng-repeat="tab in model.tabs" index="$index" heading="{{tab.title}}">
        {{tab.content}}
    </uib-tab>
</uib-tabset>
```

JS

```
model.jo = {...} // a gigantic JSON object - needs to be available in the templates.
model.tabs = [
    {
        title: "Visualized",
        content: url('vis.html')
    },
    {
        title: "Pure JSON",
        content: url('json.html')
    }
]
```

Most of the stuff I found online uses `$routeProvider` & `$locationProvider` to doctor up the URL in order to show different tabs, like this one: http://embed.plnkr.co/TMN3KNlS4Dv90SvbTQKJ/. I don't want to do that.

Is there any way to just define the `templateUrl` like you'd do for a component?

Also, I need my JSON Object, `model.jo`, in the html pages.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use `ng-include` to render template by using its template URL. The only thing you need to change in your `tabs` object is, have `templateUrl` instead of `content` property.

```
<uib-tabset active="active">
    <uib-tab ng-repeat="tab in model.tabs" index="$index" heading="{{tab.title}}">
        <div ng-include="tab.templateUrl"></div>
    </uib-tab>
</uib-tabset>
```

Change `tabs` object to

```
model.tabs = [
    {
        title: "Visualized",
        templateUrl: 'vis.html'
    },
    {
        title: "Pure JSON",
        templateUrl: 'json.html'
    }
]
```

Also, `ng-include` uses the same controller as the source, so you will be able to access the model, specifically `model.jo`,  in both of those pages. Source: [Pass parameter to Angular ng-include](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25565475/pass-parameter-to-angular-ng-include)

Comment: Cool, how could I send my data to those files? I have a big JSON object that needs to be available.

Comment: OK, found out that ng-include uses the same controller it's coming from. Source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25565475/pass-parameter-to-angular-ng-include Also, I tested it and it works.

Comment: Thanks, initially didn't work for me with : <div ng-include="app/employee/employeeAuditTab.html"></div>   but worked with :<div ng-include="'app/employee/employeeAuditTab.html'"></div> . Notice the single quotes missing in the first one. Maybe this comment helps someone.