# ngModel nested directive iterating a object tree

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I want to parse a tree into nested directives

PROBLEM :

1. can't iterate inside with ng-repeat and call the same directive again .  can't create a tree from model
2. can't get path from root object to traverse to last element ex: usercontent.child.a2.t == '30'

   ```
   userContent = {
       t: "10",
       child: {    
         "a1": {
           t: "20",
           child: {}
         },
         "a2": {
           t: "30",
           child: {
             "a23": {
               t: "20",
               child: {}
             },
             "a24": {
               t: "20",
               child: {}
             }
           }
         }
       }
     }
   ```

   PLUNKR  http://plnkr.co/edit/5CG1l68BPTpJzDPnyGE1?p=preview

Comment: So where is your problem, StackOverflow is not a place to post Requirements. Please change your question

Comment: changed text now a "PROBLEM"  ah..

Comment: FYI, this might helpfull (see second part of answer ): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19691917/how-do-display-a-collapsible-tree-in-angularjs-bootstrap/19692791#19692791